# Convert 1D array with delimeters into 2D Array

Tags: arrays, c, csv

I have been trying to find a answer for this but cant seem to understand how to implement:

I have the following data:

```
0INDEX,DATE,PACKET
0,22:3:2021  4:31:51,B987620.00  
0,22:3:2021  4:33:39,B987620.00
1,22:3:2021  4:33:46,B987620.00
```

This is stored in a one dimensional Array. There is a "," delimiter and the end of each line is represented by "/n" and shows as a carriage return in the sample above..

All good so far.

I have written the following function:

```
  char historyTableDataArray[100][5]; // I want this to contain the data above in a 2D array

  char VALUE[512] = {'\0'}; // This is the 1D array that I want to process
  
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
  {


    if (VALUE[i] == ','){
      col++;
      


      if(col==3){

        col = 0;
      }
      
      
      }
  
  else if (VALUE[i] == '\n'){

      row++;

      }

      else{

// CAPTURE CHARACTERS HERE

historyTableDataArray[row][col] = VALUE[i];
        
      }
  }
```

I want the characters to be appended to the respective row/col in historyTableDataArray but I cant find a way to do this. Code above overwrites current value. I am limited to the data starting off in a 1D array. Thanks in Advance!

Target data should look like this:

INDEX              DATE     PACKET

0 22:3:2021  4:31:51   B987620.00
0  22:3:2021  4:33:39   B987620.00
1   22:3:2021  4:33:46   B987620.00

Comment: `Serial.println` Not impossible, but is this really C?

Comment: `char* historyTableDataArray[100][5];` - this is an array of *pointers*.

Comment: Why use `sizeof(int)` in  `sizeof(VALUE) / sizeof(int)`?

Comment: Sorry that but is a typo. What would be the easiest way to convert the 1d array into a 2d array using the delimetets?

Comment: I am using this in an arduino enviroment so a variant of c.

Comment: Arduino uses [tag:arduino-c++].

Comment: Please show in your question the expected result for the example input. How exactly shall the data be stored in the destination array?

Comment: ah ok. So how would I convert 1D array into @d array using delimiters in c++?

Comment: Arduino has a [String](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) class. You can probably use some combination of `indexOf` and `substring`. Or if you want to go the c-string route, have a look at `strtok`.

Comment: I have shown target for.at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this way:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE   256
#define ROW_NB      100
#define COL_NB      5

int main(void) {
    int col = 0;
    int row = 0;
    char historyTableDataArray[ROW_NB][COL_NB][BUFF_SIZE] = {0}; // I want this to contain the data above in a 2D array

    char *s= "0,22:3:2021  4:31:51,B987620.00\n0,22:3:2021 4:33:39,B987620.00\n1,22:3:2021 4:33:46,B987620.00";

    int i;
  while (*s)
  {
    // Serial.println(VALUE[i]);
    if (*s == ','){
        col++;
        i = 0;
      //  Serial.println("comma found");
    }
    else if (*s == '\n'){
        historyTableDataArray[row][col][i] = '\0';

        row++;
        col = 0;
        i = 0;
      //  Serial.println("CR found");
    }
    else {
        // CAPTURE CHARACTERS HERE
        historyTableDataArray[row][col][i++] = *s;
    }
    s++;
  }
  historyTableDataArray[row++][col++][i] = '\0';


  for (i = 0; i< row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<col; j++) {
        printf("%s\n", historyTableDataArray[i][j]);
    }
  }
```

I assume that you already have your data in char *s

Comment: You're welcome! If that worked you should select it as answer ;)

Comment: sorry - acting like stackoverflow noob!